# Cross Browser Testing using Cucumber sequentially?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cross-browser, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I want to run the same feature files on different browsers sequentially. For example TestingExpression.feature,TestingExpression2.feature,.... all these  feature files have to run on  browsers(Chrome,Mozilla and IE) sequentially

Comment: Use three separate runners... Set the browser type in a common static variable in the beforeclass method in the runner. Use the variable to create the appropriate driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest writing a shell script (batch file) that does something like

```
cucumber BROWSER=chrome
cucumber BROWSER=mozilla
cucumber BROWSER=ie
```

and have something in your cucumber setup that picks up the BROWSER environment variable and configures whatever you are using to drive your browsers to use the appropriate one.

This will collate all you chrome, mozilla and ie results together. You can modify this approach to pass in extra arguments to cucumber so you can control which features/scenarios are run.